# Locate the singular points and state whether it is a pole, a removable singularity, or an essential singulatity: $z/(e^z-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Locate the singular points and state whether it is a pole, a removable singularity, or an essential singulatity:
>   $$f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z - 1}.$$

I obtained $z=0$. But I don't understand how to check what kind of singularity it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $z=0$, BOTH the numerator and denominator are $0$, and when that happens, it's most often a removable singularity.  One way to show that that happens in this case is to expand $e^z$ as a power series and then do two obvious cancelations.  Another is to apply L'Hopital's rule to $\lim\limits_{z\to0}f(z)$.

At what points is $e^z-1$ equal to $0$ when $z\ne0$?  Poles occur at such places.  Remember that if $z=x+iy$ then $e^z=e^{x+iy}$ $=e^x e^{iy}$ $= e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$.  If $x$ and $y$ are real then $e^x$ is positive and $|\cos y +i \sin y|=1$.  So the problem is: for what values of $x$ and $y$ is $e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$ equal to $1$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: does $f(z)$ have a limit as $z \to 0$?

Further hint: don't forget there are other values of $z$ for which $e^z = 1$.